# Toolbar disappears upon transition to new Fragment

Tags: java, android, android-fragments

There are two fragments - RuleListFragmetn and RuleFragment. The RuleListFragment fragment uses the RecyclerView element. Toolbar has app flags: `layout_scrollFlags = "scroll | enterAlways | snap"`, while AppBarLayout has app parameter: `liftOnScroll = "true"`. If the list in RuleListFragment has not been scrolled and the transition to the RuleFragment fragment has been completed, then the Toolbar is in place. If the list in the RuleListFragment has been scrolled (the Toolbar hid at the top), then when you go to the RuleFragment Toolbar fragment, it disappears. The picture below explains. Maybe in the fragment you need to reset the position of the Toolbar? But how to do that?

[image]
[image]

Comment: You should also share the XML file contents.

Comment: @ShahoodulHassan added.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your supposition is correct. As the appBarLayout lives in the activity, the toolbar stays hidden when you change fragments.

The solution is to call `appBarLayout.setExpanded(true)` in the new fragment. You can do it inside onStart, for example.

More information here: [AppBarLayout.setExpanded(boolean expanded)](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/design/widget/AppBarLayout#setexpanded_1).

Comment: Yes it helped! Thanks. True, it looks funny when, when switching to a new fragment, Toolbar animation occurs.

Comment: You can call appBarLayout.setExpanded(true, false) if you don't want the animation.

Answer (score 0):

After spending several hours trying to find out why the Toolbar wasn’t shown in a fragment, the following are **my two cents on the topic**.

***My case:*** **FragmentA** can be independently reached using **Navigation component** from four different fragments. When I navigate from three of those fragments, FragmentA behaves correctly and shows the Toolbar, but from the fourth one, it doesn’t.
After inspecting FragmentA’s layout, using the **Layout Inspector**, I found out that the **toolbar’s visibility** was `GONE` (only when using that “navigation path”).
To solve it I just added in my code `toolbar.visibility = View.VISIBLE`

This doesn’t solve the root cause, which still eludes me, but it may help someone else as it helped me.

Comment: You might want to post a new question with example code that illustrates the problem. Keep it as minimal as possible. For example with one fragment that works the way you want and one that doesn't rather than all 4 fragments in your full code base.